# Django: convert string to array

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, parsing

I have this **string** variable

```
auxi_espec = '1, 3, 5, 7,'
```

And I need to convert it to array in order to make a queryset where I filter using `__in`. (Possibly I think I'll also need to slice the last comma).

Comment: Would you explain filter using `__in`, are you referring to something on django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

```
>>> auxi_espec = '1, 3, 5, 7,'
>>> auxi_espec_lst = [x.strip() for x in auxi_espec.split(',')][:-1]
>>> auxi_espec_lst
['1', '3', '5', '7']
```

If you want to parse those numbers into integer:

```
>>> auxi_espec = '1, 3, 5, 7,'
>>> auxi_espec_lst = [int(x.strip()) for x in auxi_espec.split(',') if x]
>>> auxi_espec_lst
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django accepts a lot of [iterables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) for `in` lookup, so if format of string you mentioned is set in stone this split is enough as list of strings will do.

```
ids = auxi_espec[0:-1].split(', ')  # ['1', '3', '5', '7']
instances = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, they are awesome:

```
>>> import re
>>> auxi_espec = '1, 3, 5, 7,'
>>> indices = re.findall(r'(\d+)', auxi_espec)
>>> indices
['1', '3', '5', '7']
>>> [int(i) for i in indices]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```